# MATLAB Genetic Algorithim, f-count looks higher than expected

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, population

In MATLAB, using GA to solve a unconstrained function, shouldn't the f-count be lower than the pop size for each generation?

For example: pop_size = 10, so for the initial pop f-count=10, then for generation 1 f-count = 20 and so on, doing 10 evaluations for each generation, like the figure below:

[Function count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4EzL.jpg)

But as a GA, as we can see below, from the documentation

[Operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VgoK.gif)

if i have, for example 1 elite child, should this elite just be copied to the next generation, resulting in 9 f-counts instead of 10, for each generation?

Update: i dont have enough points to post direct pictures.
Here is the code:

```
gasol = ga(@expensive_objfun,nvar,[],[],[],[],[],[],[],gaoptions);
```

Regards.

Comment: Please embed the function code using StackOverflow's code formatting, and embed the image in the post directly, to ensure better readability of your question for anyone trying to help, as well as preserving it better for future users.

Comment: What makes you think that the GA implemented in MATLAB has some sort of memory? Perhaps such optimizations are just not implemented. OTOH, if you apply [_memoization_](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2018/07/05/memoize-functions-in-matlab/) to your cost function, you might be able to save some computations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: I update the question as requested. The questions is about how the function works.